# Generating tall array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python and numpy (I'm more accustomed to R) and have been playing around with creating arrays and want to create a tall array, where the first column is just a range with custom increment, and the second column is a unif random between 0 and 1.

I have come up with the below, but it seems very clunky and not particularly readable. Are there more efficient ways of achieving the same result in one line?

```
import numpy as np

1stcol = np.array(np.arange(1,20,0.5), ndmin=2)
2ndcol = np.array(np.random.uniform(0,1,np.shape(d)[1]), ndmin=2)
tallmat = np.transpose(np.concatenate((d,e),axis=0))
```

Comment: or get rid of the extra dimension for the input arrays to get 1D arrays and use the shortcut np.c_[a, b] sometimes easier to remember than the *stack options in a pinch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1stcol` is not a valid variable name.

In terms of efficiency this is hard to beat.

```
In [159]: d = np.array(np.arange(1,20,0.5), ndmin=2)
     ...: e = np.array(np.random.uniform(0,1,np.shape(d)[1]), ndmin=2)
     ...: tallmat = np.transpose(np.concatenate((d,e),axis=0))
```

Simpler expressions for `d` and `e` are:

```
d = np.arange(1,20,0.5)[None,:]
e = np.random.uniform(0,1,d.shape)
```

You can construct the simpler 1d arrays

```
In [160]: a = np.arange(1,20,0.5)
     ...: b = np.random.uniform(0,1,np.shape(d)[1])
```

But any function that joins them will have to expand dimensions and/or transpose in one way other other.  So the overall work will be similar.  Your solution, while 'clunky', demonstrates a knowledge of the dimension issues required for concatenate.

With the 1d arrays, these all work

```
np.column_stack((a,b))
np.c_[a,b]
np.stack((a,b),axis=-1)
np.array((a,b).T
```

My simpler expressions for `d` and `e` suggest yet another construct - make the inputs (N,1) right from the start:

```
In [171]: d = np.arange(1,20,0.5)[:,None]
In [172]: e = np.random.uniform(0,1,d.shape)
In [173]: tallmat = np.concatenate((d,e), axis=1)
```

Comment: As someone new to the language, this the comprehensive analysis I was hoping for. Trying to get a sense of best practices etc. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Given the two columns that are to be stacked as the two columns to get the *tall* array, here are few approaches with `np.vstack`, `np.row_stack` and `np.dstack` -

```
np.vstack((d,e)).T
np.row_stack((d,e)).T
np.dstack((d,e))[0]
```

---

Alternatively, we could start off with `1D` arrays and stack at the end with `np.column_stack`, like so -

```
d = np.arange(1,20,0.5)
e = np.random.uniform(0,1,np.shape(d)[1])
tallmat = np.column_stack((d,e))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of these - will try them out!